# How to categorizing a SQL Column value based

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the rate of women in a Branch basically it looks like this:

```
BranchID   | CountOfWomen   | CountofMen      | CountOfWomen/CountOfMen
(B001),           (3),            (4),                  (0.75)
(B002),           (1),            (1),                   (1)
```

So now I have the rates of the womens in a Branch:
75 % of B001 Employers are women etc...
What I need now is following:

The Rate(CountOfWomen/CountOfMen) is splitted in 3 Categories: Avarage, Low, High

Avarage means IF CountOfWomen / CountofMen is 1 so 1:1 rate

Low means  IF CountOfWomen / CountofMen is <1

High means  IF CountOfWomen / CountofMen is >1 ......More men are working than women works ..

I tried following:

I am trying to create a view and put the values in the located columns but It does not work!!

```
   CREATE VIEW MFKata2 (BranchID,High,Low,Avarage ) AS
    SELECT       MFKata.BranchID,
    Case When(MFKata.Quote > 1) As High,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote < 1) As Low,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote = 1) As Avarage
    FROM         MFKata
```

Quote is the rate(CountOfWomen/CountOfMen) I just renamed it here to better explain!

This is the code for creating MFKata:

```
CREATE VIEW MFKata (BranchID,AnzahlF, AnzahlM,Quote ) 
AS
SELECT    Frauen2.BranchID
        , AnzahlF
        , AnzahlM
        , CAST(AnzahlF as float)/CAST(AnzahlM as float) as Quote
FROM  Frauen2  
INNER JOIN Maenner ON Frauen2.BranchID = Maenner.BranchID
```

Comment: And what "does not work" mean?

Comment: I am getting error Message:

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MFKata2, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `END` for all of your case statements.

```
 CREATE VIEW MFKata2 (BranchID,High,Low,Avarage ) AS
    SELECT       MFKata.BranchID,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote > 1) THEN 1 END AS High,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote < 1) THEN 1 END As Low,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote = 1) THEN 1 END As Avarage
    FROM
```

Or you can have one column for High/Low/Average, Something like.....

```
 CREATE VIEW MFKata2 (BranchID,[Rate]) AS
    SELECT       MFKata.BranchID,
    Case When (MFKata.Quote > 1) THEN 'High'
         When (MFKata.Quote < 1) THEN 'Low'
         When (MFKata.Quote = 1) THEN 'Avarage' 
      END AS [Rate]
    FROM
```

**Edit**

Avoid creating views on top of views unless absolutely necessary, this can be achieved with a very simple select query. Something like.....

```
SELECT  BranchID
      , Case 
           When (Quote > 1) THEN 'High'
           When (Quote < 1) THEN 'Low'
           When (Quote = 1) THEN 'Average' 
        END AS [Rate]
FROM (
    SELECT    Frauen2.BranchID
            , AnzahlF
            , AnzahlM
            , CAST(AnzahlF as float)/CAST(AnzahlM as float) as Quote
    FROM  Frauen2  
    INNER JOIN Maenner ON Frauen2.BranchID = Maenner.BranchID
    ) A
```

Comment: It works both solutions :) thanks now I know where the mistake were! But is there a possibility to the the same with Outer Join so without creating views?

Comment: Thanks a pretty nice answer I think this will help somany people!